# Parameter issue in WSO2DSS

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I am using DSS 3.5.0 and have following issue while passing parameters.
Here is my resource definition looks like

```
<resource method="GET" path="v1.1/EMPLOYEE">
  <call-query href="Q_Employee">
     <with-param name="ENumber" query-param="ENumber"/>
     <with-param name="DepartmentNumber" query-param="DepartmentNumber"/>
     <with-param name="Type" query-param="Type"/>
  </call-query>
```

I am able to invoke this using

```
..<endpoint>/v1.1/EMPLOYEE/?ENumber=xx&DepartmentNumber=xx&Type=xx
```

But I want to invoke it without that extra / after EMPLOYEE i.e like

```
..<endpoint>/v1.1/EMPLOYEE?ENumber=xx&DepartmentNumber=xx&Type=xx
```

If I try to use the second URL I get this error

```
The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is ..HTTPEndpoint/v1.1/EMPLOYEE?ENumber=xx&DepartmentNumber=xx&Type=xx and the WSA Action = null.
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like this is same issue as https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1240

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in 3.5.1 and it works i.e I can access the resource using query parameters without that extra / like below

```
..<endpoint>/v1.1/EMPLOYEE?ENumber=xx&DepartmentNumber=xx&Type=xx
```

So it must be a bug in the earlier release.